# Bioshock2 installer is not running under windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, compatibility

When I try to install the Bioshock2 game under windows 7 64-bit i get the following error-

"The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher."

I try to run it in compatibility mode (as XP and admin) I get the same error. I don't understand why it is giving me this error because if it is 32bit program then it should just run like other 32 bit application I have. And I am sure Bioshock2 is not a 16bit game.

What can I do to run this program? It ran on Windows XP in the past.

Comment: The game might not be 16 bit, but the installer program very well could be.  This is not uncommon in older games.

Comment: is there any way i can run the installer

Comment: how to identify whether the installer is 16 bit or not.

Comment: This seems a bit like a question that would be better for Gaming.SE.

Comment: it is not just about gaming it is about any app that give the same error like i have pocket oxford dictionary which gave me the same error

Comment: It is unlikely you will be able to get the installer program to run.  I just did some peeking around.  Bioshock won't run in 64 bit windows anyway, even if you get the installer to work.  About your only options will be setting up your system to dual boot with XP 32 bit or possibly an XP 32 bit VM, though graphics may or may not work well in that case.

Comment: Double checking... Bioshock or Bioshock2? [Apparently Bioshock2 is incompatible with 7 64bit](https://www.microsoft.com/Windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Search.aspx?l=en&type=Software&s=bioshock)

Comment: it is bioshock2 sorry for mistake..

Comment: @BBlake VM is not going to work because my cpu does not support hardware virtualization. Is not there any software similar to DOSBOX that can run these unsupported programs.

Comment: Just VM software, which DOSBOX is also.  DOSBOX just has the DOS environment built in rather than having to set it up  yourself.  If you can't go with a VM, then about your only option is a dual boot environment.

Comment: @BBlake no game installers are 16-bit these days.

Comment: I have installed and played Bioshock 2 on my Win 7 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 1):

Bioshock is a 32-bit program and should run fine under Windows 7 64-bit, especially after you have set the compatibility mode to "Windows XP" and "Run this program as an administrator".

The only explanation is that your installation file or media is either damaged, or is not the real installer of Bioshock.

Other people have installed it on a similar configuration, although some did experience problems. An example is [here](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/topic/27493777). Most people have managed to fix these problems one way or another.

Comment: Question has been updated in that its bioshock 2. See my link in the question comments to microsoft/publisher saying its incompatible with 64bit... still... sure it should work

Comment: Microsoft doesn't like Bioshock 2 because the Steam Community feature conflicts with Microsoft's Games For Windows Live. You will have to disable it (if installed). Apart from this, I stay with my answer, since you should only get a warning while installing and have the option to continue, rather than a hard error.

Comment: If it counts for anything, Bioshock 2 works fine on my 64-bit Win7 rig.

Comment: I had this same problem as @harrymc had and it was a pain in the backside to install.  There's a great set of directions out there on how to install this correctly as there's other games that have this issue (GTA4 on PC comes to mind).  My advice is to install the Microsoft Games for Windows live first, set up an account THEN install the game via steam.